# In NetLogo 6.1: how do I find the property of sorted turtles?

Tags: foreach, netlogo

I am a new NetLogo user. How do I get the property of sorted turtles?

**clear-all**

**create-turtles 5**

**foreach (sort turtles) [ask ? [show who]]**

However, the above code produces the error below

ERROR: Nothing named ? has been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `foreach` changed with NetLogo 6 and the question mark syntax is no longer supported.  The proper syntax is shown at
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach

So, in your case the command would be

> foreach (sort turtles) [n -> ask n [show who]]

where "n" is taking on the role of the old "?".

Check out the description of anonymous procedures in the NelLogo dictionary at
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#arrow

Charles

Comment: Thank you, I saw that code in the NetLogo documentation but could not figure out how to implement it with the "sort." I also found you can sort it this way:

foreach sort-on [who] turtles [ the-turtle -> ask the-turtle [ show who ] ]

But the syntax you provided is much easier!

Cheers,
Ahmed

Comment: @AhmedAl-Jaishi If you found the answer helpful, please upvote it to accept the answer. That way, other people will know that the issue has been solved.